# How to pass argument to docker-compose

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument(
    '--strat', 
    type=str, 
)
args = parser.parse_args()
strat = args.strat
```

I would like to right my docker-compose.yml file such as I would just pass my argument from there.
I did

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mm:
    container_name: mm
    stdin_open: true
    build: .
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
       args:
           strat: 1
```

and my docker file

```
FROM python:3.10.7

COPY . .

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD python3 main.py
```

But it does not work.

Any idea what I should change pelase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update docker file to process the [build arguments](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#args) and remap them to environment variables to be processed by CMD. Try something like the following:

```
FROM python:3.10.7
ARG strat

# ...
ENV strat=${strat}
CMD python3 main.py --strat=$strat
```

But personally I would consider completely switching to [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers) instead of build arguments (so there is no need to rebuild image for every argument change).

Comment: It does not work. "mm    | main.py: error: argument --strat: invalid choice: ''". It says the strat is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The `args` thingy is for "build time" only.
If you want to run your already built image with different arguments, use environment variables or just pass them as you would with a regular binary.

like: `docker compose run backend ./manage.py makemigrations`
here you see that the `./manage.py` and `makemigrations` are two arguments passed to `backend` service defined in docker-compose.yml